# getting data js file to html

Tags: javascript, html

so i have this:

```
    "list": [
        {
            "name": "first",
            "author": "1",
            "id": 67180129,
            "vid": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwpM60h46PY&ab_channel=WhiteChocolateTwo"
        },

        {
            "name": "second",
            "author": "2",
            "id": 67089023,
            "vid": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=invRaEdZNwE"
        }
    ]
};
```

and i want to make that on an index.html file i can get access to `"name": "first"` on <p>, how do i get that?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to change the content of a paragraph to include the content `"name": "first"`? Please may you explain? At the moment it is unclear what issue you're facing

Comment: @evolutionxbox yeah i want to have like <p> with an id and then i want here to have info from that file so like i need to have access to list then "name": "first"

Comment: Good, you know what you would like to do. What part are you struggling with?

Comment: @evolutionxbox i dont know how to get access to that element so i can write its content on <p>

Comment: Iterate over data in your js file with js code 
 and create HTML elements with innerText or innerHtml 
 DOCS HERE: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

But better way is to use "JS Template Engine"

Comment: @MaximColesnic i didnt ask for that

Comment: the element needs to be selected first https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693852/989920

Comment: @evolutionxbox that didnt help me i just need to know how to access it like ```shitty.list.name[0]``` or something thats the point i dont know how to write that i need to get the value that is contained on "name" inside the first two brackets

Comment: list[0]['name'] or list[0].name

Comment: @MaximColesnic thanks

Comment: arrayOrObjectInJs[indexOrProperty] = value :)

Comment: @JvstAlf right that's cool. May you update the question to include an [mcve] of what you're trying? HTML/JS included? Otherwise we're kinda guessing at what you're struggling with

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a framework, you have to do it in your js-code.
Just select the `<p>` element and set its text to your data.

If you only want to use HTML you have to set that value by hand.